# Potential security issue with md5 filename

Tags: file, encryption, openssl, aes, pkcs#5

I've been storing files using a filename of the md5 hash of the file. This allows me to not store duplicates of the same file and avoids any filename clashes.

I want to start encrypting the contents of the file app-side (using OpenSSL PKCS5), however, by taking the md5 of the encrypted file, I lose the above benefits of the md5 filename.

Assuming the file storage was compromised, would the combination of the encrypted file and the md5 of the unencrypted file be a potential security issue?

Comment: This is better asked at security.stackexchange.com as it doesn't contain a programming question. The answer is: potentially yes. If an attacker can guess most of a message and brute-force the rest then you may lose confidentiality of the file. So you could for instance make sure that a large file is a *specific* video file, or find out if a known configuration file contains a "yes" or a "no" at a specific please - if you know or guess the other values in there.

Comment: This non-programming question should be moved to [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com).